# Questions on $d_A(x) = inf \{ ||x-a|| ; x \in A \}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, normed-spaces

#### Question:

Let $(E; ||.||)$ a normed vector space, given $A$ a non empty set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we define  the distance between $x \in E$ and $A$ as follow $ d_A(x) = d(x;A) = inf \{ ||x-a|| ; x \in A \}$

a)For $A \subset E$ find $ \{x \in E : d_A = 0 \}$

1- First let prove that $\bar{A} \subseteq \{d_A = 0 \}  $
Let say that $x \in \bar{A}$ so by definition $\exists (a_n)_n\in A : lim_{n \to \infty} ||a_n-x|| = 0$. And on an other side we have too $\forall n $ by definition of the infimum that  $0 \leq inf \{ ||x-a_n|| ; x \in A \} \leq ||x-a_n|| \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$ thus $x \in \{d_A = 0 \}$
2- Now prove that $ \{d_A = 0 \} \subseteq \bar{A} $
By absurd $\exists x' \in E : d_A(x') = 0$ but $x \notin \bar{A}$. If $x \notin \bar{A} \Rightarrow x \notin A$ because $ A \subseteq \bar{A}$. So it exists a ball $B(x'; r')$ center in $x'$ such that $B(x'; r') \cap \bar {A} = \varnothing$
And so by definition $\forall a \in \bar{A}$ I will have that $||x'-a|| \geq r' > 0$, contradiction. Because by definition all the point $x \in E$ that are not in $B(x'; r')$ have to verify $||x'-x|| \geq r' > 0 $ (if not $x$ will be in the ball).

b)For $A \subset E$ and $x \in E : d_A(x) > 0$, prove that $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists a \in A : ||x-a|| < (1+\epsilon)d_A(x)$

By definition of the infimum $d_A(x) = inf \{ ||x-a|| ; x \in A \}$. Now if we affirm by absurd that $\forall a \in A :  ||x-a|| \geq (1+\epsilon)d_A(x) > d_A(x)$ if will simply mean that it exists a greater lower bound that $d_A(x)$ and thus $d_A(x)$ is not the infimum.

I have mostly a question on "a) 2- an on b) " is this correct? I know that it looks trivial but this is maybe the reason why I am a little bit confused about what i ve written.

Thank.

Comment: Do you mean

$$d_A(x) = \inf_{\textbf{a} \in A } \|x-a\|?$$

Comment: @the_candyman thk you for your time. yes

Comment: anyone to help?